# Permission Error Setting Git URL with Capistrano

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano

I'm trying to debug deploying with a new user.  The setup currently works deploying as me, but not for bob.

```
error: could not lock config file config: Permission denied
INFO [097c7d60] Running /us/bin/env git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:me/thing.git on 1.2.3.4
```

How can I fix this?
Is it that I need to change permissions on some file?  Which one? where is the config file it is talking about?

Or is it that bob needs more permissions?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen when the user home directory is not writable by the user.

```
cd $HOME
ls -alrth
```

Check the permission for '`.`'

`git config –global` needs to create a lock file (`~/.gitconfig.lock`).
As [seen here](https://askubuntu.com/a/258300), check also the ownership of the current `~/.gitconfig`, if it already exists.